# How to generate core files on a Mac?

Tags: macos, debugging, gdb, coredump

I have a program that I hope to debug in gdb for a segmentation fault, but I'm not sure how I can generate a core file from it.

I tried `$ ulimit -c unlimited`, but when I ran the program and then navigated into /cores/, there was no core file generated there when I typed `ls`.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you enable core file generation is dependent on your shell.  The syntax you're showing is for someone using `sh` or `bash` as their shell, and it should work fine.  e.g.

```
% sh
sh-3.2$ cat>/tmp/a.c
int main ()
{
  void (*f)() = 0;
  f();
}
sh-3.2$ clang -g /tmp/a.c -o /tmp/a.out
sh-3.2$ ulimit -c unlimited
sh-3.2$ /tmp/a.out
Segmentation fault: 11 (core dumped)
sh-3.2$ ls -l /cores/core.10893 
-r--------  1 jason  admin  367714304 Nov 16 13:13 /cores/core.10893

sh-3.2$ gdb -q /tmp/a.out /cores/core.10893 
Reading symbols for shared libraries .. done
Reading symbols for shared libraries . done
Reading symbols for shared libraries 
warning: Could not find object file "/var/folders/5h/nlzqfv116jnc68g495d_3j4m0000gn/T/a-pUbMeU.o" - no debug information available for "/tmp/a.c".

.......................... done
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) add-dsym /tmp/a.out.dSYM 
Added dsym "/tmp/a.out.dSYM" to "[memory object "/private/tmp/a.out" at 0x10f5d7000]".
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x000000010f5d7f3d in main () at /tmp/a.c:4
(gdb)
```