# How to set up core dumping on a mac?

Tags: java, coredump, ulimit

I am writing code for an animation program and I have a problem. I need to set up core dumping. NetBeans is saying this: `Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again`

What do I do to start core dumping? Is there anything in terminal or at the string args[]?

Note: The program fails to run completely, so I do not know what is occurring.

Comment: Read the error message... it tells you EXACTLY what to do.

Comment: Also, unless you are debugging Java itself or maybe writing native code, you normally don't need to inspect core dumps.

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386683/how-do-i-get-a-core-dump-on-os-x-lion?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412156/how-to-generate-core-dumps-in-mac-os-x?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212000/how-to-generate-core-files-on-a-mac?rq=1

Comment: Marc B - I would not have posted a question if I read what it said and it worked, I am not completely incompetent.

Comment: @Ihavetoomanyproblems: sorry about that, then. You should have mentioned what you tried, though. A lot of people on Stackoverflow would not have bothered to follow those instructions in the error message. Core dumps on OS X seem to be a bit involved, I hope the linked questions help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, thilo. I apologize for my appalling behavior, I was unaware that people actually did that. Also, those links did help narrow down what wasn't my problem. Thanks again

Comment: You're going to have to be a little more detailed with what's happening, or specify that nothing else happens. I think, though, that if you try and run a program and it fails, your JVM is probably crashing on start.

Comment: Nothing happens, it is behaving exactly like there is a syntax error in the code except there isn't a syntax error, it is not running.

Comment: Define "not running".

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and execute the command

```
$ ulimit -c unlimited
```

In this terminal, now launch your IDE Eclipse by command line

```
$ /Path/To/Eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
```

But this is not a solution for your error when your program is running.